# Pandas Grouper with zero values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to get a count of the number of events by hour of the day. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362530/python-pandas-group-datetimes-by-hour-and-count-row?rq=1) to come up with a list of counts,  but wanted to include hours with zero events as well

Here's some sample data:

```
0   2017-10-06 13:21:37 foo
1   2017-10-06 13:21:39 foo
2   2017-10-06 13:21:42 foo
```

Here's the code I have:

```py
counts = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='LocalDateTime',freq='H'),df.foo]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

My output looks like this:

```
0   2017-10-06 12:00:00 foo 2
1   2017-10-06 14:00:00 foo 2
```

I would like it to look like this

```
0   2017-10-06 12:00:00 foo 2
1   2017-10-06 13:00:00 foo 0
2   2017-10-06 14:00:00 foo 2
```

I checked the [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) docs but didn't see any information on how to fill in missing times. What's the best way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show us some sample data ?

Comment: Absolutely! Sorry about that - I should have included that to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do need that missing timestamp, here is one way using `resample` but with apply

```
df.groupby('foo').\
     apply(lambda x : x.set_index('LocalDateTime').resample('H').count())['foo'].\
       reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much. I'm curious about whether Grouper supports it, but that's mostly academic at this point